# Stop refresh of page when updating iFrame

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new in asp .net MVC, I have a iframe in my index page and i am setting it's src from view.

I also have a textbox outside of iframe, now I wanted to update only the area which is inside the iframe not the full page so that i can retain value of text boxes. I also have some links in the form of tree at the left of iframe ,so even if user clicks on any link i want to retain value of text boxes.

So please tell me any idea or code in asp mvc ,i have been worked on asp .net web form based model where it was so easy, but how the same thing can be achieved in asp .net mvc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your question have to do with update panels?

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no such update panel for mvc, it's completely different!

You need to set the value of your controls in the view, mvc doesn't have something like viewstate to keep the value of your controls.
I recommend you to fallow some tutorial to get started, someone like nerd dinner..

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx

http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

Best regards